# multiple tab content area in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop a very simple jquery tab where I would have the flexibility to add multiple tab content areas in the page. I can make a single tab work..but when i am trying to make it more generic where I am saying I will increase the number of contents by just increment the wrapper by naming the class like container_1, container_2...etc

This is what I have so far which is as obvious as it might be is not working

```
    $('<li class="spacer"></li>').insertAfter('.tabs li');
$('.tabs li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
$('.container').hide();
$('.container:first').show();

for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    $('.container_[i] .tabs li a').click(function () {
        var title = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($(this).hasClass('inactive')) {
            $('.tabs li a').addClass('inactive');
            $(this).removeClass('inactive');

            $('.container').hide();
            $('#' + title + 'Content').show();
        }
    });
}
```

here is my markup

```
<div class="container_1">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a id="tab1">soum</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="tab2">sherry</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="tab3">neighbor cat</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container" id="tab1Content">Soum's content</div>
    <div class="container" id="tab2Content">Sherry's content</div>
    <div class="container" id="tab3Content">neighbor cat's content</div>
</div>
<div class="container_2">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a id="tab1">Freddy</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="tab2">Teddy</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="tab3">Brady</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container" id="tab4Content">Freddy's content</div>
    <div class="container" id="tab5Content">Teddy's content</div>
    <div class="container" id="tab6Content">Brady's content</div>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/LF4rp/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over complicating things. With this setup you can actually have the content div use a class instead of an id but I did not change that part because I thought maybe you are using IDs for a reason

http://jsfiddle.net/LF4rp/18/

```
$('.containers .tabs li a').click(function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('id');
    var parent = $(this).closest('.containers');
    parent.find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    parent.find('#' + title + 'Content').addClass('active');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container_1 containers">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a id="tab1">soum</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="tab2">sherry</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="tab3">neighbor cat</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container" id="tab1Content">Soum's content</div>
    <div class="container" id="tab2Content">Sherry's content</div>
    <div class="container" id="tab3Content">neighbor cat's content</div>
</div>
<div class="container_2 containers">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a id="tab4">Freddy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="tab5">Teddy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="tab6">Brady</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container" id="tab4Content">Freddy's content</div>
    <div class="container" id="tab5Content">Teddy's content</div>
    <div class="container" id="tab6Content">Brady's content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: none;
}
.container.active {
    display: block;
}
```

to open the containers with jquery you can do

```
$('.containers .tabs li:first-child a').addClass('active');
$('.containers').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.container:first').addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LF4rp/19/

Comment: @Huangism--thanks. Yes. I see how I was making it overly clomplex

Comment: Most of the time using jquery you can avoid looping since jquery is doing that already

Comment: One thing though, how would I show the content for the first tab visible at all times for all the wrappers? Right now on page load all of them are closed.

Comment: right, just add active class to the first tab and tabs anchor in the html.. it is doable in jquery as well